# Do any methods have to be synchronized if there's only the main thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, methods, synchronize

Do I really need to synchronize any methods if I'm not creating any threads (exception is the main). If so, can someone give a reason why and provide some examples please.

Comment: I just wonder where you heard that you need to. Of course you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't create any threads of your own, then no, you should not need to use the `synchronized` keyword. That's assuming you're not writing J2EE servlets or filters, or a library that others (who are using multiple threads) can call.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need any synchronziation in this situation, synchronization is  when **multiple** threads access shared data.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronized methods are used when you don't want two threads to operate on any synchronized method at one time. If the application is single threaded there is no point taking a lock and adding an overhead of synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not as it will affect your performance. Synchronization should not be used if you are doing all in one thread.

Comment: Synchronization in singlethreaded application will not affect perfomance. But it can in multithreaded.

Comment: @inikolaev Premature optimization.

Comment: @inikolaev in single threaded app there will not be any context switch but still to execute the synchronized block the thread need to have acquire lock on the object which is a overhead.